# How to test for Granger Causality in non-time-series data

Tags: hypothesis-testing, granger-causality

I would like to know how can I test for Granger Causality in data that does not present a sequential behavior. As far as I understand, at least in economic models, it is assumed that the data is stationary and that a Vector Autoregressive (VAR) model is suitable to explain the data. However, when the data is not sequential (it is not a time series), a VAR model is no longer suitable, since there is no concept of lag. In this situation, what model should I use to test for Granger Causality? What statistical test should I use?

Comment: Well, the concept of Granger-"causality" (he was the first to admit that it is quite remote from what most people would associate with the concept of causality) says that a variable Granger-causes something if it tending to take, say, large values in the past means that the "something" will also tend to take, say, large values. It is therefore not clear if that concept makes sense without temporally ordered events.

Comment: @ChristophHanck, when explaining Granger causality, I would always mention the conditioning part (the information in the lags of X that is **incremental** to the information in the lags of Y). I have seen some examples of misunderstanding of the conditioning part here on CV.